I cannot run parallelized code on a remote server using R
I am trying to run a simple code with the terra package in R using a remote server. When the code is not parallelized, the script runs fine. However, when I attempt to parallelize the code, I encounter an error. I dont think is a memeory issue becuase the data below is simple.
library(terra)
testfun <- function(i) { 2 * sqrt(i) }

r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
x <- c(r, sqrt(r), r+50)

x
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source(s)   : memory
names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
min values  :     1,     1,    51 
max values  :   100,    10,   150 

When code is not paralleized
test1 <- app(x, fun=testfun, cores =1)
test1 
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source(s)   : memory
names       : lyr.1,    lyr.1,    lyr.1 
min values  :     2, 2.000000, 14.28286 
max values  :    20, 6.324555, 24.49490 

However, when code is run in parallel with 2 cores, I get reading from a connection error.
test2 <- app(x, fun=testfun, cores =2)
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection


try supplying the cluster yourslf: cores = parallel::makeCluster(n_cores) or cores = parallel::makePSOCKcluster(n_cores)

@Ric I tried that approach with a simple function but got the same error
